# How to update image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, crud

I am new in codeigniter. 
    I am using codeigniter for this project. 
    I have not getting how to update image form data in the database.
    I have inserting ,showing data in the database is done . 
    but i cant understand how to update image in the database. 
    This is a method which i use to update existing images but i am unable to 
    update image. 
    I have successfully uploaded image in my database.

```
public function update($id) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tite', 'title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug', 'required');    
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['category'] = $this->category_model->all();
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('backend/pages/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/footer');  
    } else {
        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {              
            // upload featured image
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/page';
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '1080';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);                
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                $data['page'] = $this->page_model->find($id);
                $data['category'] = $this->category_model->all();
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/header');
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/navigation');
                $this->load->view('backend/pages/edit', $data);
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/footer');
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $featured_img = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                var_dump($data);
                var_dump($featured_img);
            }
        } else {

            $this->page_model->update($featured_img, $id);
            redirect('backend/page', 'refresh');    
        }    
    }
}
```

This is a method which i use to update existing images but i am unable to update image.
    This is a model where i send data. 
    I have successfully uploaded image in my database.

```
public function update($featured_img, $id) {
    $data = array(
        'title' => ucwords($this->input->post('title')),
        'slug' => strtolower($this->input->post('slug')),
        'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
        'featured_img' => $featured_img,
        'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id')
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('pages', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, it will update `featured_img` only if it contains data (if user upload image).

Controller :

```
public function update($id) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tite', 'title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug', 'required');    
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['category'] = $this->category_model->all();
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('backend/pages/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('backend/templates/footer');  
    } else {
        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {              
            // upload featured image
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/page';
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '1080';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);                
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                $data['page'] = $this->page_model->find($id);
                $data['category'] = $this->category_model->all();
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/header');
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/navigation');
                $this->load->view('backend/pages/edit', $data);
                $this->load->view('backend/templates/footer');
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $featured_img = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                var_dump($data);
                var_dump($featured_img);
            }
        } // else {

            if (isset($featured_img)) {
                $param['featured_img'] = $featured_img;
            }
            $param['id'] = $id;
            $this->page_model->update($param);

            redirect('backend/page', 'refresh');    
        // }    
    }
}
```

Model :

```
public function update($param) {
    $data = array(
        'title' => ucwords($this->input->post('title')),
        'slug' => strtolower($this->input->post('slug')),
        'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
        // 'featured_img' => $featured_img,
        'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id')
    );
    if (isset($param['featured_img'])) {
        $data['featured_img'] = $param['featured_img'];
    }
    $this->db->where('id', $param['id']);
    return $this->db->update('pages', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hey it is giving me $featured_img is not define. i want to update existing image if user select new image otherwise there should be existing image.

Comment: Sorry I have mistyped the code, now it's fixed. Yes, it will update data on database only if new image is uploaded

Comment: Thank You Very Much Hasta Dhana Now It works for me.